# How to make requests on microPython more efficient?

Tags: web-scraping, esp32, micropython

I´m currently programming an esp32 with micropython.
It runs a bigger project for university and I have a problem with the following code.

```
import urequests as request

def readWebsiteData():
        response = request.get(url='https://www.heizpellets24.de')
        response_text = response.text

        index1 = response_text.find("fr chartPrice")
        index2 = response_text.find("fr small")

        offset1 = 15
        offset2 = 10
        len1 = 6
        len2 = 5
        
        price = response_text[(index1+offset1):(index1+offset1+len1)]
        trend = response_text[(index2+offset2):(index2+offset2+len2)]
        response.close()

        return [price, trend]
```

Im trying to read two numbers from a website to include them in my program. The code itself runs fine, however if I include it in the whole program I get a memory error in line 5. (memory allocating failed 20000bytes)

Is there a way to not read the whole html response (over 1000 lines of code)?

Btw I know the code with the offset for reading the numbers isn't very elegant and it doesn't work if the website makes even small changes.

I already tried running gc.collect() before calling the function.

response_text = response.text[543:579] also didn't help (I´m guessing it just safes the whole html response anyway?)

I displayed the memory before calling the function:

- memory free: 89952
- memory allocated: 21216

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to load the content of a large web page into the memory of a resource-limited embedded device.

Your best option is probably to avoid loading the content into memory all at once, which is what happens when you run:

```
response_text = response.text
```

If you look at [the implementation of the `.text` attribute](https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/blob/c113611765278b2fc8dcf8b2f2c3513b35a69b39/python-ecosys/urequests/urequests.py#L26), it loads all the response content into memory:

```
@property
def content(self):
    if self._cached is None:
        try:
            self._cached = self.raw.read()
        finally:
            self.raw.close()
            self.raw = None
    return self._cached

@property
def text(self):
    return str(self.content, self.encoding)
```

You could instead iterate over the response content in smaller blocks; something like:

```
import urequests as request

def readWebsiteData():
        response = request.get(url='https://www.heizpellets24.de')

        # Here I'm using a 2K buffer but you could make this substantially
        # larger if you want (16k/32k/etc)
        buf = bytearray(2048)

        price = ''
        price_offset = 15
        price_len = 6

        trend = ''
        trend_offset = 10
        trend_len = 5

        while True:
            numbytes = response.raw.readinto(buf)
            index = buf.find(b'fr chartPrice')
            if index != -1:
                price = buf[index + price_offset:index + price_offset + price_len].decode()

            index = buf.find(b'fr small')
            if index != -1:
                trend = buf[index + trend_offset:index + trend_offset + trend_len].decode()

            if numbytes < len(buf):
                break

        response.raw.close()
        return price, trend

price, trend = readWebsiteData()
print('price:', price, 'trend:', trend)
```

Running the above code on my esp32 results in:

```
price: 390,20 trend: +0,05
```

In this code we're optimistically assuming that the content we want isn't split across blocks. We're fortunate it works without additional logic in this specific case.